# how to go about inserting a table into Markdown Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have a table of about 40 rows that I want to enter into a Jupyter notebook, I know the usual method but it's gonna take time to write down. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: "I have a table of about 40 rows"—in what format?

Comment: An option: At 40 columns, you may want to save this as a file in comma separated or tab-separated text file and view it as a separate table viewer in JupyterLab? You can link to the file from inside the markdown cell in the associated notebook, like `[open the table in table viewer](test_csv.csv)`. You can test this by clicking `launch binder` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyterlab) and then making a small test table in text with the text file saved as `.csv` or `.tsv` extension, depending on your delimiter.

Comment: Another option if you have the table in something microsoft based already, that you can convert the table to HTML format and then use that in the markdown cell because markdown can display HTML. Or use [the markdown tables generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to help you convert the table text.